# Rails way to write SQL EXISTS for Active Record?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, exists

I have the following setup:

```
class Company
  has_many :users
end

class User
  belongs_to :company
end
```

I need to get all companies that doesn't have a user with specific name, let it be 'David'.

It's easy to do the opposite, find all companies that have a user named David:

```
Company.joins(:users).where(users: { name: 'David' }).distinct
```

But I don't know how to do the original task in one SQL request.
I tried this:

```
Company.joins(:users).where.not(users: { name: 'David' }).distinct
```

but it doesn't work as I thought.

So I made a raw SQL solution, where the query is:

```
"SELECT companies 
  FROM companies 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT users 
      FROM users 
      WHERE users.company_id = companies.id 
      AND users.name = 'David')"
```

So I am wondering if there is a way to do this task in rails way, using joins and where methods, or may be there is also a method for EXISTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end ActiveRecord doesn't have full power of SQL, so I ended up with raw SQL.

Still there is a gem that adds EXISTS to ActiveRecord:
https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists

If you want to avoid raw SQL at any costs, you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace joins with includes

```
Company.includes(:users).where.not(users: { name: 'David' })
```

Comment: Could you please comment on the difference between `includes` and `joins` and why the proposed change should work?

Comment: Basically the `includes` uses eager loading whereas `joins` uses lazy loading. You can check more [here](http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/)

Comment: @Aqabawe The problem with your query is the same as with joins. For example, we have only one company with two users - David and Goliath. Your query will return that company (should return nil), because it really searches for **companies, that have at least one user with name different from David**. So the problem remains unsolved.